# After the redirect of login.html, how does urls, views and templates know which user they are dealing with?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using the login.html provided in django.auth (default it is in templates/registration/login.html right?) Here is login.html:

```
<!-- templates/registration/login.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Notice I did not notify any information (such as user.username)to pass to next url. I change the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to a url in a app which
is:

```
app_name = 'ride'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Notice again there is no  in the url. Then it will go to views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'ride/home.html')
```

And there is only a request object to pass to template.
And here is ride/home.html:

```
<!-- ride/templates/ride/home.html -->

{% extends 'ride/base.html' %}

{% block title %}HOmeeeeeeeeeee {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ user.username }}
{% else %}
  <p>Welcome to CJ & XY's Ride Sharing Service!</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'login:signup' %}">signup</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I use user.username in this template and it displays perfectly.

So my question is, how does this final template know which user is authenticated and which user's username? Because from the beginning, I did not pass any information of user like user.id or something when redirect, urls and views. This is so magic.

Could anyone give me the key? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a few steps here.

When you [log in](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L86), Django stores the ID of the authenticated user, and the backend that authenticated them, in the session. The session is basically a dictionary of values stored in the database and associated with a particular user via an ID stored in a cookie on the user's machine. (Note, the ID in the cookie isn't related to the ID of the user, though.)

On each request, the [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L16) checks this ID and fetches the relevant user from the db, making it available as `request.user`. (In fact, this is done lazily, so the db isn't hit if you don't access the user.)

When you render a template, the [auth context processor](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/context_processors.py#L46) gets the user from the request and makes it available in the template as the `user` variable;

Comment: So is it the case that after login, this session will exist and user's data can be referenced in the app as long as user does not logout?